# Removing characters after X digit number for entire column

Tags: r, regex

I have a column of identifiers:

```
c('ABB123a','ABB123b','ABB123c','ABB125','ABB125b','ABB1110','ABB1110aa')

#desired output
c('ABB123','ABB123','ABB123','ABB125','ABB125','ABB1110','ABB1110')
```

What's the easiest way of removing the character following the pattern 3 characters, 2 to 4 numeric in R?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Are you saying 3 letters followed by between 2 and 4 digits? Or some character followed by the number 3? As commented above, please clarify your question and show the expected output?

Comment: Why do you have the tag `sed` added if you wanted to do it in `r`?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've added examples to highlight the issue with variable character/numeric lengths as well as desired output.

Comment: AAAAAAH you want to remove characters that are after a number and till the end.

Comment: `sub("(?i)(?<=\\d)[a-z]*$", "", x, perl = TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do what you want:

Your data:

```
x <- c("ABB123a","ABB123b","ABB123c","ABB125a")
```

Alter the data using `gsub`by removing the last (`$`) character in the string

```
x_new <- gsub("\\w$", "", x) 
x_new
[1] "ABB123" "ABB123" "ABB123" "ABB125"
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. How can the gsub be loosened to account for just letters after numbers, such that if there's no letter suffix, the number is not removed, while allowing for variable lengths of letters/numbers? ie 123 vs 123a should both be 123 in the end. Similarly, 1234 and 1234aa should also both be 1234.

Comment: Data:
`x <- c("ABB123aaa","ABB123b","ABB123","ABB125ccc")`
Pattern:
`pattern <- "[A-Z]{1,}[0-9]{1,}"`
Matches:
`matches <- gregexpr(pattern, x)
identifier <- regmatches(x, matches)
identifier <- unlist(identifier)
identifier
[1] "ABB123" "ABB123" "ABB123" "ABB125"`

Comment: `{1,}` says: at least once; if you know the maximum number of occurrences, you can specify the upper limit, thus: `{1,5}`